# mod_rewrite - stop it appending a question mark and the original query

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a URL like this:

```
http://my.site/apps/123
```

which I'd like to redirect to

```
http://my.site/app/123
```

using mod_rewrite. However, when I use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^/apps/(.*)$ /app/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I get a 500 and this error in the logs:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. 
Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. 
Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Thu Sep 13 12:58:13 2012] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 127.0.0.1] r->uri = /index.php
```

The final URL in the browser looks like this:

```
http://my.site/app/123?/apps/123
```

**Why is Apache appending ?/apps/123 on to the URL?**

I guess if I can avoid this then I can avoid the infinite recursion problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect my.site/apps/123 to my.site/app/123, simply use :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^apps/(.*)$ app/$1 [L,R=301]
```

**Edit :**

You added the rule in the wrong place, try this instead of your rules :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^apps/(.*)$ app/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I still get the same problem. To be clear: I get "?/apps/123" appended onto the new URL.

Comment: /apps/123 redirects to /app/123?apps/123. And then I get a 500 due to the infinite recursion.

Comment: your rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]` is what is causing this, you realy need that ?

Comment: No, the index.php rewrite works fine. If I completely remove it I still get the same problem (e.g. if I remove the last 2 lines of your edited answer).

Comment: Bizarrely it's all working now so I'm ticking this answer. No idea what the initial problem was - but restarting Apache and clearing the cache in Firefox solved the problem.

Comment: the browser cache remenbers the redirections
you must always clear your cache after a modification